# Boost asio library for networking (http client)

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm trying to compile a utility in C++ with Visual Studio 2015, which requires the **Boost asio** library for networking (http requests).
The same solution includes a project to build this Boost asio library, but I had to download the boost_1_59_0.7z file. So far, I was able to download it and built was good, but I found the build generated like 11 libs with different names (libboost_**chrono**-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib, and 10 more but with date_time, filesystem, log-setup, etc...).
On the other hand, the project that requires this lib is looking for a library named boost_1_59_0.lib, so my question is how do I know which of the generated libraries is the right one to use for networking (I don't see any name related with asio or networking...).
I would appreciate any guidance on this.

Thanks
Gus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Boost.Asio [doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html):

> By default, Boost.Asio is a header-only library. However, some developers may prefer to build Boost.Asio using separately compiled source code. To do this, add `#include <boost/asio/impl/src.hpp>` to one (and only one) source file in a program, then build the program with `BOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION` defined in the project/compiler settings. Alternatively, `BOOST_ASIO_DYN_LINK` may be defined to build a separately-compiled Boost.Asio as part of a shared library.

So, by default Asio is header-file-only and for most uses does not require linking against any Boost library.

But, boost Asio does depens on other boost components likt Boost.System, Boost.Thread(not nessesary) etc. to support better async operations and some error codes ( boost::system::error_code and boost::system::system_error).

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105592/boost-asio-linking-and-libraries) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089245/boost-asio-as-header-only) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

`boost asio` **is** a header-only library but `asio` networking depends upon `boost system` for error messages, which **isn't** a header only library. 
In short, your code needs to link to `boost-system` and it may also require `boost-chrono` for `asio` timers.

Note: `boost` supports `autolinking` in `Visual Studio`; so you just need to add the path to the `boost` library directory to the `Library Directories` configuration properties, e.g.:

```
$BOOST_ROOT\stage\lib
```

Where `$BOOST_ROOT` is the directory where you installed `boost`.

You do not need to add `boost-system` or `boost-chrono` to `Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`. However, you may need to add `Windows` networking libraries, such as: `wsock32` and `ws2_32`.